# Neo4j. Create graph from two tables

Tags: neo4j, edges

I have two csv files with nodes and edges.

```
nodes:

big, adjective
arm, noun
face, noun,
best, adjective

edges:
big, face
best, friend
face, arm
```

I want to create graph with relationships by edges and add nodes group: noun and adjective.

I use this command to create relationships:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:copperfield_edges.csv' AS line MERGE (g:G {word1 : line[0]}) WITH line, g MERGE (j:J {word2 : line[1]}) WITH g,j MERGE (g)-[:From_To]->(j);
```

but in this case each word appears two times. How can I do only unique relationships of words and add noun and adjective group?

I want to get something like this http://joxi.ru/1A5QX6MH6LZ1AE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assignen the `G` label to all nodes in the first column and the `J` label to all in the second column. Since you have one identifier (e.g. `big`, `face`) for every word, use one label for all, e.g. `Word`
Try the following:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:copperfield_edges.csv' AS line 
MERGE (g:Word {word : line[0]}) 
MERGE (j:Word {word : line[1]}) 
MERGE (g)-[:From_To]->(j);
```

Based on your nodes csv file, you can assign an additional label indicating if the word is an adjective or noun:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:nodes.csv' AS line
MERGE (w:Word {word: line[0]})
FOREACH (n in (CASE WHEN line[1] = "adjective" THEN [1] ELSE [] END) | 
 set w :Adjective  )
FOREACH (n in (CASE WHEN line[1] = "nound" THEN [1] ELSE [] END) | 
 set w :Noun  )
```

Since you cannot set labels dynamically, I've had to use the `FOREACH` trick documented at http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/06/17/neo4j-load-csv-handling-conditionals/

If your graph is more than a handful of nodes consider using creating an index before running `LOAD CSV`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Word(word)
```